# How to align multi line array in Vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

In PhpStrom there are some facilities which are `short array` `Align when multiline` and many more

*Here is an example*

http://prntscr.com/pyfkc8

[Another Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2vep.jpg)

Now I want to align array in vs-code ....

## How can I do that?

### This is a normal Array

```
$x=array(
 0 => "zero",
 123122 => "one two three",
 251=> "two five"
);
```

## Now I want Like this

```php
$x=[
   0   => "zero",
   123 => "one two three",
   25  => "two five"
];
```

**Is this possible is vs-code?**

Comment: The second one is short form of Array .. So, What do  you exactly want  ? 

just to reformat code ? or you want to a normal to be a short array

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are looking for a *extension* called **"ALIGNMENT"**

> JUST INSTALL IT AND ALIGN THE SECTION OF CODE YOU WANT JUST BY
>   SELECTION.

***HERE is a list of Extension:***
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=tag%3Aalignment&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance

***And Here is the Extension i'm talking about:***
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=annsk.alignment

Comment: Alignmet plugin is not exactly working like sublime code in vscode